# I didn't see my buttons in my page

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my HTML page i didn't see my buttons...please help me...

```
#container
{
    position:relative;
    width:700px;
    height:400px;
    border: 2px solid black;
        background-color:#888;
    margin: 50px auto 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.box
{
    position:relative;
    width:600px;
    height:300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 50px auto 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#button
{
    margin:47%;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:2%;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $c =0;
    function next()
    {
        var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
        $c +=1;
        if($c >= boxes.length) $c = 0;
        for (var $i=0;$i<boxes.length;$i++)
        {
            boxes[$i].style.display  = "none";
        }
    boxes[$c].style.display  = "block";
    return false;
    }
    function prev()
    {
        var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
        $c -=1;
        if($c < 0) $c = (boxes.length-1);   
        for (var $i=0;$i<boxes.length;$i++)
        {
            boxes[$i].style.display  = "none";
        }
    boxes[$c].style.display  = "block";
    return false;   
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="box"><img src="img1.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="img2.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="img3.jpg"/></div>
<div id= button>
    <button id="bwd" onclick="return prev()"><<</button>
    <button id="fwd" onclick="return next()">>></button>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I have no idea what this means, please edit this question so that it is an actual question where you give enough detail about your problem and any errors you might be getting

Comment: Well if you dindt see them you do see them now, so the problem is fixed

Comment: Probably a typo in your question but your also missing your quotes on your div id `button` `<div id="button">`

Comment: @MarkWalters: it's perfectly valid as it is and will do what you would expect. (If you expected the whitespace to make it a new attribute, it doesn't; the whitespace is ignored.)

Comment: Note, however, that `container` and `button` are not good IDs. They're the sort of thing that should be a class.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed, seems reasonable to me.  Guy provided relevant code and a specific question...

Comment: BTW @user, welcome to SO...sorry for the immediate flurry of attacks :)

Comment: user here is a working one http://jsfiddle.net/9Y77g/14/ just remove the position:relative; in #container :) notice below the button that you are looking for.

Comment: thank you for all of your suggestions but i didn't solve problem...@bot in jsfiddle where is my buttons...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
.box {
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 50px 45px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It may be because you're using `<` and `>` inside your buttons so the browser interprets your HTML wrong.

Try `&gt;` for `>` and `&lt;` for `<` and it should work properly.  (These are called [HTML entities](http://htmlentities.net/html/entities/).)

---

The other reason may be that your margin is moving the buttons under another element.  Try not styling the buttons at all (remove the CSS) and see where that gets you.

Answer (score 2):

Don't write `<` into your html code unless you want to start a tag.

Replace

```
<div id= button>
    <button id="bwd" onclick="return prev()"><<</button>
    <button id="fwd" onclick="return next()">>></button>
</div>
```

with

```
<div id= button>
    <button id="bwd" onclick="return prev()">&lt;&lt;</button>
    <button id="fwd" onclick="return next()">&gt;&gt;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Same bat-time, same bat-channel...

Comment: By editing this also i didn't solve my problem..